# Can XSLT execute a shell script at the OS level?

Tags: shell, xslt, saxon

I have a production flow that combines XSLT and some shell scripts in about 4 steps before it reaches completion.  I execute each step manually at the moment.

I'm using Saxon 9 from the command line in Linux.  Can I have the xsl's execute shell scripts.. instead of me?

(I know I could achieve the desired result in another way with Ant or Make.. but prefer to stay in XSLT if it is not a huge effort to do so)

**Update**: I've minimized my shell scripts and sped things up using Xproc. I'm not entirely satisfied with the result, but Xproc has improved life. Kai's suggestion below looks good.. but I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Not answering my own Q..just adding a bit of an epilogue 9 months later. XPROC turns out to fulfill the need I had above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call java.lang.Runtime.exec() in the same way as any other external Java function.

Comment: Is the answer. Not the one I wanted to hear, because I'm not Java savy. BTW, your XSLT 2.0 book has a prominent spot on my desk lately, I like it..thanks.

Comment: is this possible with xalan-c++ as well? what would i use instead of java.lang.Runtime.exec()

Answer (score 6):

I'm not Java savvy either, but I found with Michael Kay's tutorials on the [Saxonica website](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility) it's doable.

Here's what I did and what's working well for me:
In the root element of the XSLT stylesheet I assigned a namespace for the function (in my case I'm using it for unzipping, so I named the prefix unzip, but that could certainly be anything):

```
xmlns:unzip="java:java.lang.Runtime"
```

I am defining a variable with a file path for a batch file to be called later. Then I am using

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$batchFile}" method="text"> ... </result document>
```

to create the batch file. (Unzipping could be certainly done with just a command, but I found the batch file version more handy as I needed to combine the unzip-command with some change directory command and other little stuff. And furthermore using a batch file opens up a world of more elaborate tasks that could be called from the XSLT sheet.)

When I need my batch file be executed, I insert an xsl:message like this:

```
<xsl:message>Executing <xsl:value-of select="unzip:exec(unzip:getRuntime(),concat('cmd /c /y start ',$batchFile))"/></xsl:message>
```

Hope that helps,
best regards,
Kai

Comment: Thank you. A creative solution. I'll keep this in mind for future projects.

Comment: is this possible with xalan-c++ as well? what would i use instead of java.lang.Runtime.exec()