# Is it possible to count files in directory using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I need a way to count the number of files in a directory and store that back to a variable .

```
<xsl:variable name="no_of_files" />
```

I am not getting any hint to proceed

Comment: Do you want to do that from within the stylesheet? You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15804837/696632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull in and count all XML documents in a directory with Saxon 9 doing e.g. `count(collection('file:///C:/dir/subdir?select=*.xml'))`, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections. But the files need to be well-formed XML documents for that to work and will be loaded and parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, which would not involve the expense of reading and parsing all the files in the directory, and which would include non-XML files, is to use the EXPath file extension. This is implemented in Saxon 9.5 PE.

See http://expath.org/spec/file

```
count(file:list($fir, $recursive))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to achieve this in pure XSLT. But even if it is possible - XSLT is clearly not a natural fit for the task.

There are other languages that are more apt to handle a file system. Either

- count the files in a directory beforehand (with a shell script or with the language that is executing Saxon) and pass this information to the XSLT processor as a parameter. See for example the [Saxon documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html).

or

- execute external code from within XSLT to retrieve the file count. @Michael-O suggests one way to approach this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504106/can-xslt-execute-a-shell-script-at-the-os-level/15804837#15804837).

---

On a different note, it might be interesting to know why you need a file count in the first place. Usually, if you describe your [*problem* rather than your attempted solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), answers become more helpful.