# XSLT 2.0 / Java: System Bell

Tags: java, xslt

I multi-task while I run transforms.  I would like some template matches and fallbacks to ring the system bell to catch my attention.

**Attempt 1**: a java call to ring the system bell, but have been unable to make it work (my java knowledge is limited).

As a starting point, I tried to alter this template which is a working 4 second *sleep* implementation in the OxygenXML environment with Saxon PE. No success.

```
 <xsl:template name="sleep" xmlns:thread="java.lang.Thread">
    <xsl:value-of select="thread:sleep(4000)"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

**Attempt 2**: I tried various `<xsl:message select="'asci bell foo'"/>` to try and ring a system bell.  No luck.

Amplifying info: I'm using an up to date Linux Mint (an Ubuntu variant).

What can I do to ring the system bell in a transform? Most likely in the form of a call template.

Comment: Writing a line `asci bell foo` to a terminal usually does not emit a beep - not even when you spell "ASCII" correctly. Did you confuse the character code for a bell with its literal description? Try emitting the ASCII code itself.

Comment: I didn't literally use foo. I used various formats of "\007" or  "\a" or "BEL"

Comment: I don't think you will be able to output the control character using `xsl:message` as it is control character which is not allowed in XML and `xsl:message` output is subjected to XML rules (I tried `<xsl:message select="codepoints-to-string(7)"/>` and Saxon first emits a warning and then throws an error for that attempt `FOCH0001: Invalid XML character [x 7]`). As you use oXygen, perhaps it is better to ask in their support forums whether you can set watches or breakpoints for XSLT execution or debugging that cause an acoustical alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following approach on Windows 10 with Saxon 9.6 and 9.7 PE from the command line, both in a normal command prompt as well as in a PowerShell window:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:sys="java:java.lang.System"
  xmlns:ps="java:java.io.PrintStream"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs sys ps"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template name="bell">
  <xsl:variable name="serr" select="sys:err()"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="ps:write($serr, 7)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:call-template name="bell"/>
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does give a sound when run against an XML input document having a `foo` element, but it looks as there is only a single sound produced, even if the template is matched several times.

Comment: It does the same for me in Linux that it does for you in Windows. The beep is also faint.

Answer (score 0):

I checked Martin's Q as the answer. He answered the question as it was asked.

However, the system bell was faint, so I ended up going in a different direction when I remembered this Stack Q: [Can XSLT execute a shell script at the OS level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504106/can-xslt-execute-a-shell-script-at-the-os-level). Demo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:os-command="java:java.lang.Runtime"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs os-command"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:call-template name="tone"/>         
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tone">
  <xsl:value-of 
   select="os-command:exec(os-command:getRuntime(),'aplay /usr/share/sounds/linuxmint-gdm.wav')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
    <xsl:template name="tone"  xmlns:os-command="java.lang.Runtime">
    <xsl:value-of select="os-command:exec(os-command:getRuntime(),'aplay /usr/share/sounds/linuxmint-gdm.wav')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It plays a wav file in Linux Mint (not a shell script). The command line could be changed to your situation.

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but this will probably only fire off one or two times a day.