# Is it possible to call a program during a XSL transformation if something match a template

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to call a program (e.g. a Perl script) during a XSL transformation if something match a template

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="a"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <!-- 
        I have elements 'b' and 'c' inside a 'row' as well.
        I want to execute 'perl "value_of_b" "value_of_c"' and insert output here'
    -->
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q.: *Is it possible to call a program during a XSL transformation if something match a template*

The answer depend on your xslt processor.

For  perl have a look to  [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.94/LibXSLT.pm) `register_function`.

> Registers an XSLT extension function mapped to the given URI. For example:

```
 XML::LibXSLT->register_function("urn:foo", "bar",
   sub { scalar localtime });
```

Comment: Looks good. I had plans to use _xsltproc_ but a pure Perl version is even better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. I run something like this inside OxygenXML successfully.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:os-command="java:java.lang.Runtime"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs os-command"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="a"/>
        </p>

        <!-- build the OS command string -->
        <xsl:variable name="cmd-string" select="concat('perl ',a,' ',b)"/>

        <xsl:value-of 
            select="os-command:exec(os-command:getRuntime(),$cmd-string)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have not tried it outside Oxygen. And also, I was *not* successful getting this to execute a bash script. Perl may pose a similar problem.

Here's a link to the original [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34579317/87370) at this.